# Capturing SSH output as variable in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, stdout

I've been struggling with this problem when writing a bash script.
Basically, I want to measure the time of a program on a remote server, so I use the command:
`/usr/bin/time -f %e sh -c "my command > /dev/null 2>&1"` to execute the program.
However, it appears that I cannot capture the output of my command (SSH) to a variable at all. In fact, the result (time) keeps getting printed out to stdout.

The full code is:

```
respond=$(ssh ${fromNode} /usr/bin/time "-f" "%e" "'sh' '-c' 'virsh migrate --live ${VM} qemu+ssh://${toNode}/system --verbose > /dev/null 2>&1'")
```

The value of respond is just empty, though the time is printed out to the standard output.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/130443/remotely-run-script-on-unix-get-output-locally

Comment: If you want to capture the result of a MySql query into an array, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061108/470749

Answer (score 49, accepted):

"time" command prints result to stderr, not to stdout. Thus it is not piped into your variable.

You should reroute stderr to stdout to achieve what you want:

```
 result=$(ssh host time "command" 2>&1)
```

And your full code can look something like this:

```
 respond=$(ssh ${fromNode} /usr/bin/time "-f" "%e" "'sh' '-c' 'virsh migrate --live ${VM} qemu+ssh://${toNode}/system > /dev/null 2>&1'" 2>&1)
```

Comment: Great. Works exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you very much for your great help! And by the way, I just simply use &> /dev/null for the virsh migrate part since I intended to discard the output anyway

Answer (score 3):

Try swapping the order of your redirections around (to `2>&1 >/dev/null`). Your current code is sending both stdout and stderr to /dev/null (so I'm kind of curious as to why *anything* is printed at all).

Why is this necessary? The syntax `2>&1` means 'duplicate stdout (descriptor 1) as stderr (descriptor 2)'; in effect, stderr is made into a copy of the current stdout. If you put `>/dev/null` first, then stdout is first redirected to /dev/null, and then stderr is pointed at the current stdout, i.e. /dev/null.

But if you put `>/dev/null` second, stderr will first become a copy of the current stdout (the normal output stream), before stdout is redirected. So the command's stderr prints to the tty (or the interpreter) as if it came from stdout, while stdout is silenced. This is the behaviour you want.

From `man bash`:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the command
>
> ```
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ```
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs  only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was duplicated
>   as standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

Comment: Those redirections affect only 'virsh' command (silencing it), not the output from 'time' command.

Comment: Though I'm curious, as well, why output of command with 'verbose' flag should be silenced :)

Comment: Ah, you are right. I misread the command. Seems my quote-matching skills need improvement :)

Comment: By the way, great explanation - I always wondered about this behavior, your answer explained things.

Comment: The verbose option is to force the virsh migrate command to keep the process foreground. It's not really needed, but just in case some virsh version may send the process into background.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation about the redirection thing. But I think the problem here was that I need to redirect the output of the time command into the standard output